# Catch exceptions in javax.swing application

Tags: java, swing, exception, awt, catch-all

I'm working with `javax.swing` to make an aplication which generates forms from XML Schema (using JAXFront library) and stores the data filled by the user them into XML documents.

I have put try-catch-finally blocks when I need it, but I have a little problem catching exceptions when the main thread ends (The AWT threads are still running).

I have two classes which do the main work and other classes which aren't important for the question:

- ***Main class***: It has the following structure. Initializes the application and runs the main frame

  ```
  public class Main { 
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          readArgs(); // An INI file with the app config
          Model model = initializeElements(args); // My model class
          try {
              MyFrame mfr = new MyFrame(title,model);
              mfr.visualize(); // Assembling view and setting visible
          } catch( Excepion e ) {
              doCleanUp();
              System.exit(-1);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- ***Frame Class***: Generates the view and listen events

  ```
  public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener,MenuListener { 
      // Some attributes
      // Other mthods without importance
      /**
       * Compose the elements, add listeners and set visible the frame
       */
      public void visualize() {
          generateFormPanel();
          setListeners();
          validate();
          setVisible(true);
      }

      public MyFrame(String title, Modele model) {
          super(title);
          createElementsUsing(model);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          // Code to manage events
      }
  }
  ```

Well, the problem is the following:
When the visualize function is exectuted from the main method, the view is generated and showed. At that moment is when I lose the control of the exceptions catching. Then my question is if **there are some way to catch the possible RuntimeExceptions throwed after this point**.

I hope you understand my English and can answer the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simplest version is to set the default uncaught exception handler:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

But that catches uncaught exceptions thrown in other parts of the program aswell.

You could however catch only runtime exceptions thrown off the swing event dispatching thread using a proxy (See [this](http://ruben42.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/catching-all-runtime-exceptions-in-swing/) page for more information, copied code from there):

```
class EventQueueProxy extends EventQueue {

    protected void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent newEvent) {
        try {
            super.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // do something more useful than: t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now installing it like this:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().push(new EventQueueProxy());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your first solution resolves my probelm. I can't give you a vote, but take it!

Answer (score 1):

After you have called `visualize()` the only thread running is the Swing/AWT event dispatch thread. If you want to catch any exceptions you will need to do so in any of your listener methods that are called on this thread e.g.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  try {
    // Some code here
  } catch(RuntimeException e) {
    // Handling code here
  }
}
```

To prevent boilerplate you can have this code in a super class.

Note that you can also set a [default uncaught exception handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) if you want to catch anything not already dealt with by the Swing/AWT thread.

Note also that in general it is best practice to not catch subclasses of RuntimeException if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

to MyFrame constructor. Not sure though, but worth trying.

Comment: In order to control the exit events I have `setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` and `addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){...});` which does the clean up.